# Jenkins job workspace directory name change

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have an old jenkins v2.138 upgraded to v2.332. with this upgrade, there is a change related with workspace structure.
with v2.138, it was like /jenkins_home/workspace/jobaaa-SFSBDFEXXXXXXXXXXX@script/pom.xml
with v2.332, it is now /jenkins_home/workspace/jobaaa@script/SFSBDFEXXXXXXXXXXX/pom.xml
with this change, our pipeline script fileexist("pom.xml") doesn't work anymore.
If we don't want to change our pipeline script, is there any setting to set back the workspace structure as in v2.138.
Thank you very much for any input!

Comment: If the `pom.xml` is a part of your source code,  it should be in your job workspace, you can print job workspace by `echo ${env.WORK_SPACE}` and list job workspace  by `sh 'ls -l ${WORKS_SPACE}'` to check its structure and find out where is pom.xml

Comment: I believe it's WORKSPACE, not WORK_SPACE. And you should either just refer to the workspace root and content by reference (ie: "./") or use car $WORKSPACE, not hard-coded.